# Canot create udp connection on mono

Tags: c#, mono, udp

I can not create a UDP connection:

```
public void Connect(String host, int port)
{

    System.Net.IPAddress address = Dns.GetHostAddresses (host)[0];
    this.hostport = new IPEndPoint(address, port);

    this.socket = new Socket(
        AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
        SocketType.Dgram, 
        ProtocolType.Udp
    );

    this.socket.BeginConnect(this.hostport, new AsyncCallback(socket__onConnect), this.socket);
}

private void socket__onConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // It is never called on udp connections :(
    try 
    {
        Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
        client.EndConnect(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Try connect but socket__onConnect is never called.

With TCP works fine but UDP doeas not works.

I have perrmissions to connect udp port:

```
nc -v -u host.com 53
```

Works fine.

Comment: UDP is connectionless: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol *"UDP uses a simple **connectionless** transmission model with a minimum of protocol mechanism."*

Answer (score 0):

Mono bug? try this:

```
 Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp) { ExclusiveAddressUse = true ; } ;
```